# _co.open is not a function:run method based on condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a method  that method  should be executed based on the condition, here i am opening a modal  window on marker click on a map.

```
    if(this.showMobile){
open(content) {
  this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
  this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
  }, (reason) => {
  this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
  });
  }
}
```

after enclosing that open method inside the if statement "TypeError: _co.open is not a function" getting this error. want to open the modal window based on the condition.

```
<div id="dvMap"  (click)="open(content)"  style="width:900px;height:600px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place condition *inside* open:

```
open(content) {
  if(this.showMobile) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
}
```